# UDP Traffic to route53

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just deployed a simple web application in AWS EC2, and created domain name, and load balancer. the problem is that I see logs and traffic coming from many locations around the world. Is this something AWS is doing or kinof attacks or what?
In Addition, the cadence of these logs are very low. maximum 80 request by hour.
would you please help if have seen same behavior
here is an example of logs that Route53 is tracing:

```
**2022-06-13T09:37:24.000-04:00
1.0 2022-06-13T13:37:24Z xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx A NOERROR UDP DFW55-C3 184.188.69.13 -
Field   Value
@ingestionTime  
1655127481041
@log    
xxxxxxxxxxxxx:route53/logs.com
@logStream  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
@message    
1.0 2022-06-13T13:37:24Z xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx A NOERROR UDP DFW55-C3 184.188.69.13 -
@timestamp  
1655127444000
edgeLocation    
DFW55-C3
hostZoneId  
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
protocol    
UDP
queryName   
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
queryTimestamp  
2022-06-13T13:37:24Z
queryType   
A
resolverIp  
184.188.69.13
responseCode    
NOERROR
version 
1.0**
```

Comment: Could you please format the logs to make it readable?

Comment: Are you saying that these are logs made by Route 53 of DNS queries made to Route 53 to resolve your domain name?

Comment: yes, I am getting requests from unknown IP addresses

Comment: Welcome to the Internet where people scan websites and IPs for many reasons. That's normal and should encourage you to secure your application :-)

Comment: @Maurice thank you for confirming that. I will start spending more money :)

Comment: You don't [pay](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) for DNS queries related to ELB, CloudFront, Beanstalk etc. You might, of course, have to pay for WAF if you want to protect your public endpoints.